# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'double'

Tags: c#

Recently started learning C# and still haven't quite got the hang of how type works which produces errors like this, my code should return true or false but returns the following error message.

> ..\Playground(32,15): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'double'

Here is my code, can anyone explain why I get this error message?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


    namespace SoloLearn
    {
        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double fPrime(double n)
            {
                if (n==2){
                    return true;
                }
                return Math.Pow(2,n-1)%n==1;
            }
            //Example usage
            Console.WriteLine(fPrime(7));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The expression `Math.Pow(2,n-1)%n==1` evaluates to a boolean value while your function returns a double.

Comment: Looks like a case of System Hungarian gone bad.  Call it `IsPrime` instead, change the return type to `bool`.

Comment: It's an example of an alternative method to IsPrime, I'm learning about classical algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a **`Boolean`** value and your function definition is to return double, change it as,

```
bool fPrime(double n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is returning a double. So you need to change your method signature if you want to return a boolen (i.e true or false)

```
bool isPrimeNum(double n)
        {
            if (n==2){
                return true;
            }
            return Math.Pow(2,n-1)%n==1;
}
```

Its is also good practice to prefix methods that return a bool with ***is***, for example :

```
isPrimeNum(){...}
```